# Pause flag not present in cpuinfo?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I read [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-3488E3C1-33C3-4444-9D72-CB428DCA3658.htm) something I would try but when i do "cat /proc/cpuinfo", there is no `pause` flag for an intel cpu. Some other cpus have it.

So :

1) Does it really means that `pause` is not activated on this cpu ? (core 2 duo 2006, sse2 flag is there)

2) I should use the "rep nop" alternative then ?

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: why do you think `cpuinfo` flags should include the `pause` item? There is no such flag in `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/capflags.c`

Comment: @wRAR: I saw it on other cpus. Weird.

Comment: @jww: oops, i am sorry !

Comment: @jww it is on topic, because he is asking how to write asm code for a cpu that does not have the `pause` instruction.

Comment: @Jester - fair enough. The close vote has been retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intel instruction set reference says:

```
This instruction was introduced in the Pentium 4 processors,
but is backward compatible with all IA-32 processors.
In earlier IA-32 processors, the PAUSE instruction operates
like a NOP instruction. The Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon processors
implement  the PAUSE instruction as a delay.
```

So your core 2 duo does have it, but even on processors that don't it will still work like a `NOP`.